# How To Specify JPA relationship with same setting object detached in JAVA 8

Tags: java, jpa, mapping, cascade

I'm trying to map the following case in JPA with Annotations:

[DB Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rycJp.png)

So, we have a **root** object that has a relation with the **source** which we are going to save in our transaction, but after a processing of that **root** object we will obtain the **result** object

Here my mapping:

```
public class Root {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="source_id", unique= false, nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=false)
    private Source source;

    @Column(name = "label", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private String label;
}

public class Source {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "label", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private String label;
}

public class Result {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="source_id", unique= false, nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=false)
    private Source source;

    @Column(name = "label", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private String label;
}
```

My UseCase:

I save the object Source & Root 
MYSQL:

```
INSERT INTO source (label) VALUES ("FIRST"); -- id: 1
INSERT INTO root (source_id, label) VALUES (1, "MY FIRST");
```

So then processing, i want to save the object Result to link this value with the source object, but i want to only link for SELECT (and not for INSERT/UPDATE/REMOVE)

My code with lombok:

```
SourceEntity source = SourceEntity.builder().id(root.getId()).build();

ResultEntity result = ResultEntity.builder().source(source).label("REFERENCE TO FIRST").build();
dao.save(result);
```

Error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`result`, CONSTRAINT `result_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `source` (`id`))
```

I understand that in the mapping I am doing something wrong but I can not find the error, maybe the cascadeType? I tried `CascadeType.DETACH` too.

Thanks,

Comment: You say you only want the relationship only for select and setting all to insert and update false. How do you want to store it?

Comment: I want a relation between the result and the source (I do not insert the source object), I just want to insert the reference to the source of the object (That has been created before) and when I bring the result object I bring the source.

Comment: You have to remove insertable=true, updatable=false and then the relationship will be set. Insertable/Updateable is for the foreign key not the object itself

Comment: the type of cascade is fine? I am trying what you have proposed, but in test I have the same error, I think it is because it does not flush the database.

Comment: The error is only in test mode, i think that the save is not impacting the changes.

Comment: Save does not trigger the SQL statements. This is done on COMMIT you could call flush() in your tests on the repository.

Comment: Excelent!  I must to add 
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)